# Strange foreach loop after modifying array

Tags: php, loops, foreach, pass-by-reference

As I wrote some code, PHP confused me a little as I didn't expected the result of the following code:

```
$data = array(array('test' => 'one'), array('test' => 'two'));

foreach($data as &$entry) {
    $entry['test'] .= '+';
}

foreach($data as $entry) {
    echo $entry['test']."\n";
}
```

I think it should output

```
one+
two+
```

However the result is: http://ideone.com/e5tCsi

```
one+
one+
```

Can anyone explain to me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, see also https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29992.

The reference is maintained when using the second foreach, so when using the second foreach the value of `$entry`, which points still to `$data[1]`, is overwritten with the first value.

P.s. (thanks to @billyonecan for saying it): you need to `unset($entry)` first, so that your reference is destroyed.

Comment: +1 - Side Note: You can break the binding between the variable and content by using `unset()` - http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php

Answer (score 0):

This is mentioned specifically in the [documentation for foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). You should `unset` the loop variable when it gets elements of the array by reference.

> Warning
>
> Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the
>   foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().